# How to get different status count by product id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have got the result form a complex query below

```
SELECT o_items.sku,
       o_items.name        AS 'title',
       o_items.qty_ordered AS 'quantity',       
       s_orders.base_amount_paid AS 'paid/unpaid'
  FROM sales_order_payment s_orders
 INNER JOIN (SELECT s.sku, s.name, s.qty_ordered, s.order_id
               FROM sales_order_item s             
              INNER JOIN (SELECT p.entity_id
                           FROM catalog_product_entity AS p                         
                          INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_int AS a
                             ON p.row_id = a.row_id
                          WHERE VALUE >= 0
                            AND                               
                                a.attribute_id =
                                (SELECT attribute_id
                                   FROM eav_attribute                                 
                                  WHERE attribute_code = 'is_darkhorse')) as q
                 ON s.product_id = q.entity_id             
              WHERE s.created_at BETWEEN '2019-01-14' AND '2019-01-16') o_items
          ON
             s_orders.parent_id = o_items.order_id
```

[image]
this is the order data those have been paid or not paid yet. Amount is representing paid and Null representing unpaid status

I am trying to generate below result but couldn't succeed and need help. Actually this result is showing how may quantity of a product has been paid and how many not paid yet. This would be result of above fetched data. 
[image]

Please guide me how can i proceed to achieve these result.

Comment: share the query in text format not image.

Comment: @MuhammadWaheed i want to generate result from above first table. so don't worry about my query and consider first table result as a table.

Comment: What's the DBMS ? Oracle or MySQL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this. `...` represent existing code.

```
select .... , sum(case  when s_orders.base_amount_paid  is not null 
                        then o_items.qty_ordered
                        else 0 
                  end) as paid, 
              sum(case  when s_orders.base_amount_paid  is null 
                        then o_items.qty_ordered 
                        else 0 
                  end) as unpaid
From .......
```

Comment: thanks but this will give the row count sum not quantity sum

Comment: your answer was too close i have to do a minor tweak  i replaced "1" with o_items.qty_ordered  Now it sum qty instead of orders row count.  Kindly do this change in your answer btw i am accepting your answer. Thanks you so much.

Comment: really nice of you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if` and `ifnull` functions together(*presuming you're using mysql as DBMS*)

and `GROUP BY` expression

```
SELECT c.sku, c.name, 
       sum(if(ifnull(base_amount_paid,0)=0,0,1)) as paid,
            sum(if(ifnull(qty_ordered,0)=0,0,1)) as unpaid
  FROM catalog_prod_ent_derived c
 GROUP BY c.sku, c.name
```

where `catalog_prod_ent_derived` represents your whole query as a subquery.